# D3.js syntax comprehension

Tags: d3.js, syntax

I have been learning D3 for the past weeks and I have an understanding of the concepts and created some animations and maps with it, however I am having trouble understanding one syntax construct:

```
attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 + ",0)");
```

I know what it does and how to use it, however I wonder why I need to put "+" before and after the "100"? I haven't had much experience with javascript before...

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to use '+' in your example. But you have to do it when 100 is value of the variable eg:

```
var a = 100;
attr("transform", "translate(" + a + ", 0)");
```

The '+' in this case is simple string concatenate operator and it just adding the text "100" inside the string. So it's result is: `attr("transform", "translate(100 ,0)");`